# Flexbox List Overflowing Out of Container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a little card setup going that includes some links at the bottom/footer of each card. I set those up using flexbox, however, they're extending out of the containers.

I tried specifying a width to the list as well as footer divs, but cannot make it wrap. Any thoughts?

```css
.container {
    /*added by the editor to correctly reproduce the problem*/
        width:250px;
    /*-----*/
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #404040;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .footer ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .footer li+li {
        margin-left: .5rem;
    }

  .footer li {
      line-height: 1.5rem;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div>
          Header Stuff
       </div>
       <div class="body">
          Body Stuff
       </div>
       <div class="footer">
          <ul>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `they're extending out of the card parent (not the footer parent)` - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Check my answer bellow, I think I understood what you meant and provided the right fix, despite someone downvoting for no reason whatsoever -_-

Comment: @FacundoCorradini Since with the now removed codepen (which you did with your edit) and a working code snippet, it became more clear what was wrong. Comment removed, upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just have an incorrect property name on your .footer ul. Instead of `flex: row wrap`, should be `flex-flow: row wrap`

Since that property value is not valid the rule is ignored, and there is nothing telling the browser to wrap the flex items in that flex container.

```css
.container {
        width:250px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #404040;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #888;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .footer ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        /*only change is here*/
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        /*--------*/
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .footer li+li {
        margin-left: .5rem;
    }

  .footer li {
      line-height: 1.5rem;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div>
          Header Stuff
       </div>
       <div class="body">
          Body Stuff
       </div>
       <div class="footer">
          <ul>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Footer Link</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```